# Style a multiple select box (but not a combo) in css

Tags: html, css

I need to style all the multiple select boxes of a page without using classes, but I don't want the styles to be applied to the combos in the same page. How do I call ONLY the multiple select?

HTML:

Apply styles to:

```
<select multiple> <option>option 1</option> <option>option 2</option> </select>
```

But not:

```
<select> <option>option 1</option> <option>option 2</option> </select>
```

I'm looking for something like `input[type=text]` but for the multiple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
select[multiple]
```

As in:

```
$('select[multiple]').addClass('selected');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lw9bk/